# Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion', when it *is* present in aspnetdb

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis

I have a web site that works as it should on our company intranet, which I am now trying to deploy on a hosted web server. Unfortunately when a user clicks Log In it crashes with:-

Server Error in '/' Application. Could not find stored procedure 'dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion'.

If I go on to the remote server's desktop, log in to Management Studio with the username and password in the site's webconfig.cfg file, then I can open the aspnetdb database, and execute dbo.aspnet_CheckSchemaVersion without any error messages or access issues.

I have read numerous other postings on this error message and none of the suggestions have helped, but I am new to web site administration and may be missing something obvious.

The web site is coded in VB.NET, and compiled with Visual Studio 2012.  Third party tools used are Fusion Charts and AJAX Calendar Extender.  The .NET Framework version is 4.5.

The remote server runs Windows Web Server 2008 R2 with IIS version 7.

The database server is a named instance of SQL Server Express 2008 R2.

There are five users defined in the aspnet_Users table, which I added using the .NET Users applet within IIS.  I can no longer use the user management tools in IIS because I had to upgrade the site's application pool to .NET 4.0 which does not support them.  However I can see the users are there.
There are no Roles defined in aspnetdb.

Does anyone have any ideas what I could be missing?

Comment: Does your connection string specify the database? If not, then perhaps the application is trying to execute that stored procedure in the login's default database, not the aspnet database.

Comment: Thanks very much that was it.  I changed the "Initial Catalog" in the connection string to aspnetdb, now I can log in.

Answer (score 0):

Try recreating the ASP.net procedures with something like:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -S DBServerName -U DBLogin -P DBPassword -A all -d DBName
```

Answer (score -1):

Just so this question is no longer "unanswered", I will echo Aaron Bertrand's comment, which the questioner said was the correct answer:

Does your connection string specify the database? If not, then perhaps the application is trying to execute that stored procedure in the login's default database, not the aspnet database. –  Aaron Bertrand Feb 17 at 14:44

Thanks very much that was it. I changed the "Initial Catalog" in the connection string to aspnetdb, now I can log in. –  user3319440 Feb 17 at 16:30